# java: static methods and inheritance. Is there a way around this?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, static-methods

I have the following problem:

There's an engine that invokes a static method of SuperClass (which we will call SuperClass.StaticMethod). I have no access to the code of the engine but I can reflect on it.

I subclassed SuperClass (generating SubClass) and I was able to edit the private fields inherited from SuperClass through reflection. Everything ok up to this point.

The engine has a class (let's call it Constants) which has static final instances of a lot of classes, including SuperClass, but not my SubClass, since it's not part of the engine.

Now, SuperClass.StaticMethod does the equivalent of this:

```
public int StaticMethod(int i)
{
    if(i == 0)
        return Constants.SuperClassInstance.Field_1;
    else if(i == 1)
        return Constants.SuperClassInstance.Field_2;
}
```

Both SuperClass.Field_1 and SuperClass.Field_2 are private (and they are not static, people were thinking they were, so I'm editing the question a bit), but the static method has visibility of them because it's a member of SuperClass. As I said, I was able to set the values of those fields on my inherited SubClass through reflection, but because of the way SupperClass.StaticMethod works, as shown above, that has no effect on it.

I don't think I can change SuperClassInstance.Field_1 and Field_2, or I would break the way SuperClass works, slightly, but sensibly.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It's not at all clear *why* you're trying to break the access control in the first place.

Comment: Because I need my class to work together with the engine. I need the engine to render my SubClass correctly. I simplified the code because that's the essence of the problem, but It's a rendering issue.

Comment: It sounds like the engine isn't designed to work in this way. Bending code against its design is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: It really isn't. The engine expects me to write a custom renderer for my SubClass. I thought maybe there would be a simpler solution that would save me from going that far. I'd harmlessly hack the engine to avoid writing and registering my custom renderer. I once heard a good programmer is a lazy programmer...

Comment: When your "simpler solution" involves setting fields with reflection because you don't otherwise have access to them, it's worth following the *intended* design instead.

Comment: I set them in my own SubClass, just as if they were protected instead. The engine design is really flawed. It fully cooperates with it's own classes, and changes things from private to protected on the next release if it has to, in order to support a new class. But it fails on supporting custom classes.

Comment: One thing a class design can do is depend on limited use, change, etc. of private variables, constants, etc.  If you use reflection to access things that are otherwise private, then you don't know what effect it will have.

Comment: @user2212990 The problem is that you don't know what *else* your hackery might break. If the API expects devs to register a renderer, register a renderer. Internal details are internal, and might change.

Comment: @Dave Newton That's true. If something change, my code could break. I'm aware of that. That's also the reason why I don't want to edit the bytecode of the engine itself at runtime to make things easier for me, because what is now harmless, can lead to catastrophe on the engine's next release. If my code break between engine releases, I can fix it quickly to work with the new release, but if my code breaks the engine, that could take a lot longer to fix.

Comment: @rcook It can't do any harm because I access those private fields from the point of view of my SubClass. They are my SubClass' inherited private fields. Their value remain the same when the runtime type of an instance is SuperClass. But if it's SubClass, then my values are in place. This is harmless to the engine, trust me on that one. What could cause trouble would be changing things that belong to the engine. That I want to avoid, and I'd go as far as writing the cursed custom renderer before I'd do that.

Comment: Everyone is so against my approach, you guys won't even consider answering with something other than "don't do that!"...

Comment: @user2212990: I would advise that most of the guys on this forum who are answering you right now, especially Jon Skeet, are extremely knowledgeable and are telling you that for a reason.

Comment: "...I access those private fields from the point of view of my SubClass..." - but they are *static* private fields, what makes you think your subclass has a different copy than the superclass? I would think changing them would change them for both super and subclass references.  What makes you think it would even be a good idea for your subclass to have a separate copy?

Comment: @rcook they are not static... I wrote SuperClass.Field_1 and SupperClass.Field_2 just to be clear. They are instance fields. Look at the actual code. The way Constants uses a static final instance of those fields to access them. (Although in java that doesn't mean much. You have access to static members through instances for some reason). Anyway, sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but Field_1 and Field_2 are not static.

Comment: @Andrew Martin I know, but maybe the question has at least a theorical relevance? From the point of view of the java language, and leaving asside the fact that it's a bad practice to tamper with private fields through reflection, is there a solution to this? Most likely there is not, but "no, what you want is impossible unless you edit the bytecode of SuperClass.StaticMethod" would be enough, that's all I'm saying. I know it's good advice you are giving, but it's relevant to know if it's theoretically possible.

Comment: So, StaticMethod is not a static method?  "...not clear enough..." is right.  I suspected before now that you didn't understand the background of what you were asking, and stating that you don't understand why instance methods can access static method makes it clear.  There is no theoretical (or practical) use, in general, of knowing if you can do this or how.

Comment: @rcook obviously StaticMethod is static. The fields are not. And I never said they were. I did say StaticMethod was static though. And What I don't understand is why you can access a static member using the dot operator on an instance:

`Integer x = 5; x.parseInt(str);`

The fact that you can do that is what I was talking about. The 2 statements above make no sense. How much clearer must I be until you understand what I'm saying?

Comment: Let's try summarizing it this way: you want to change the values of things that are constants to the engine.  You assume that the engine has no dependency on these at compile time, so you can change them at run time, hopefully before the engine refers to them.  You need to do this so your class will work with the engine, but these are not things that "belong to the engine".  If, in the next version, they just remove these values, you are up the creek.  And you're doing this to avoid writing a custom renderer, because this will be simpler.  Good luck.

Comment: @rcook I'm not changing constants, I'm changing inherited private fields. Everything the engine does is unaffected. The engine lacks a constructor that would let me set those private fields instead of needing reflection to do it (the engine is poorly designed, as I mentioned). What I do is harmless and I'm sure of that. What I want to avoid doing (editing the bytecode of the renderer at runtime) may not be so harmless, and that's why I'm asking if there's another way. Up until now, nobody said either "yes, there is a way" or "no, there is not". But everyone has a strong opinion to express.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me to be an XY problem.  That is most of your issues are with the design.

For one, what is the purpose of having a private static final?  Since it is final, it might as well be public.  It is something that I have seen regularly, but I think it is, generally, a bad practice.

Making something static, essentially makes it global.  In the case of things like a singleton, there is a desire to hide the globalness, of a static variable.  However, there are typically helper functions that reveal useful functionality of this "hidden, global".

It sounds like the parent class lacks those methods that make the parent class fully useful.  Is there a way that you can change the design of the parent class, rather than utilize all these hacks to make your project work?

Comment: No, unless I use reflection to change the very code of the engine classes at runtime. That would be an even greater hack.

Comment: "Since it is final, it might as well be public" - no, it can have a use for static methods without littering the public namespace, there are good reasons you might not want it public.  Static and public are orthogonal characteristics.  There are only helper functions if you want users to have access to the hidden variable or whatever, that's why there are different access classifications.